# Hibernate DB showing /u0000

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate

```
    <hibernate-mapping>
        <class name="User" table="users">
            <meta attribute="class-description">
                This class contains the user detail.
            </meta>
            <id name="id" type="string" column="id">
            </id>
            <property name="displayName" column="displayName" type="string"/>
            <property name="status" column="status" type="string"/>
            <property name="kind" column="kind" type="string"/>
        </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>
```

and config like these

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- 顯示實際操作資料庫時的SQL -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <!-- 將顯示的SQL排版，方便觀看 -->
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>
        <!-- SQL方言，這邊設定的是MySQL -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <!-- JDBC驅動程式 -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <!-- JDBC URL -->
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/comp4111-database?autoReconnect=true&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8

        </property>
        <!-- 資料庫使用者 -->
        <property name="connection.username">samwalker</property>
        <!-- 資料庫密碼 -->
        <property name="connection.password">*sam505*</property>

        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

        <!-- 物件與資料庫表格映射文件 -->
        <mapping resource="User.hbm.xml"/>

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

when I try to get single user from session.load, it is fine. However when I use the following code:

```
public void getUsers() {
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    try{
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        List users = session.createQuery("from User").list();
        users.forEach(user -> print(((User)user).getId()));
        tx.commit();
    }catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        session.close();
    }
}
```

it appears to showing /u0000(empty space in Idea console), I have no idea why, can anyone help me on this? Thanks a lot